# I want to restrict a user to insert his performnce only once per day

Tags: c#, sql-server, restriction

I wrote this code, but it allows users to enter their performance record more than once a day while what I want is for the user to only be able to do so once a day.

At first I wrote the condition like this: `if (dt.Rows.Count < 0)` but in this case only else part is working and user can not enter his record at least once..

```
 protected void subtbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=incible;Integrated Security=true");

        connection.Open();

        string sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM prfrmnce where u_name='" + unamelbl.Text + "' and datetime ='" + Calendar1.TodaysDate + "'";

        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, connection);

        SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);

         sqlDa.Fill(dt);

         if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)

         {
             // Open the database connection

             string myConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=incible;Integrated Security=true";

             SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString);
             con.Open();
             //Query to insert images name and Description into database
             SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into prfrmnce(u_name,designatn,datetime,todaytask,tmrwplan) values(@uname,@dsgntn,@date,@twrk,@tmrwpln)  ", con);
             //Passing parameters to query
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", UserName.Text);
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dsgntn", desigtxtbx.Text);
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@twrk", tfortday.Text);
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tmrwpln", pfortmrw.Text);
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", Calendar1.TodaysDate);

             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
             resultlebel.Text = "data added successfully";

             //Close dbconnection


             con.Close();
             tfortday.Text = string.Empty;
             pfortmrw.Text = string.Empty;
             GridView1.DataBind();
         }
         else if (dt.Rows.Count > 0) 
         {
             errorlabel.Text = "You have already submitted your today's performance";
         }


    }
```

Comment: The `errorlabel` reads "submitted your today's".  It should be "submitted today's"

Comment: i m not here to correct my grammar... :P

Comment: You are here to get help, though, and free help at that.  If someone's willing to take the time to offer a suggestion surely the least you can do is accept it with good grace?

Comment: But what about my actual problem?

Answer (score 2):

I would guess this is a `DateTime` problem. DateTime is not a day, it has also hours, minutes, etc.

You should work with the date part of the date only.

So in your query,

change

```
and datetime ='" + Calendar1.TodaysDate + "'"
```

to

```
and cast(datetime as date) = '" + Calendar1.TodaysDate.Date + "'"
```

**By the way, you should work with parameters, not string concatenation.**
See [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: i changed it but problem is not resolved.. even i worked with parameters.. the statements of if condition are executed even when it is false..

Answer (score 0):

Is this query correct...

```
string sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM prfrmnce where u_name='" + unamelbl.Text + "' and datetime ='" + Calendar1.TodaysDate + "'";
```

The problem might be Calendar1.TodaysDate gives date and time so you will always get dt.Rows.Count as 0